# Java and Flutter in installed in system in Administrator account, Path is set but I am not able to use with different administrator account

Tags: windows, installation, path, account, administrator

I am working on Windows 10. I have to work on 2 projects at the same time so I decided to create one more user in the same system and give the administrator right to both accounts but I am not able to use my Flutter or Java in 2nd account. when I am trying to download(java & flutter) again and try to set the path so it's already added in the environment variable how can I download it 2 times and save the path 2 times on the same system?

how i can use Java and Flutter with 2nd account?

suggest me some ideas or refer to any video & blog to solve this issue.